# How to customize the_content()

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My problem is that i need to customize "the_content()".

The thing is, i've already created a separate file for the content of a page, and if i use it(the function), this is what i get in this specific order:

```
"title"

"content"

"pagination"
```

What if i want to put a "hr" tag between "content" and "pagination"? What if i want to put pagination before the title?

I need to use hooks to edit all the content of "the_content()"? I can't do it natively subscribing a file?

How can i customize it?

Comment: Why do you not just put <hr /> after <?php the_content(); ?>  ??

Comment: I need to put between content and pagination, like i described...

Comment: So <?php the_content(); ?><hr /><?php //pagination code ?> ?? Sorry, I feel like I'm stabbing in the dark here. Can you please divulge more code, it'll make this a lot easer.

Comment: But the_content already has pagination. How can i split it? If i use the_content it prints all my posts (considering that im looking at an "all posts" page), with pagination already.

Comment: No, there's something missing here. Wordpress does not just throw out pagination on a whim.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customise the content of a post after it is retrieved from the database and before it is printed to the screen, you can use the the_content filter as described here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content